# Postman PUT returns success, but parameters are null in response body

Tags: postman, json, rest

I am trying to update employee details on following URI
**http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/update/24**

The request body is:

```
{
    "employee_name": "DorisWan",
    "employee_salary": "50000",
    "employee_age": "25"
}
```

and the actual response looks like this:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "id": "24",
        "employee_name": null,
        "employee_salary": null,
        "employee_age": null,
        "profile_image": ""
    }
}
```

I am expecting response like:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "id": "24",
        "employee_name": DorisWan,
        "employee_salary": 50000,
        "employee_age": 25,
        "profile_image": ""
    }
}
```

Why the actual response contains "null" values though the status is success.

I have added content-type as application/json in the request header parameters.
Also tried passing the request via form-data still getting same response.

Comment: You should update the proper Id in your url in which your updating the employee details it is perfectly explained in their documentation so url will be like http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/update/25 where 25 is your employee id

Comment: Request you to spend some time in reading API documentation before you are into testing

Answer (score 2):

Welcome.

You need to read the [documentation](http://dummy.restapiexample.com/update) in detail, it shows an example of a request body for PUT method:

```
{
    "name":"test1",
    "salary":"1123",
    "age":"23"
}
```

There is no `employee_` in the names of the attributes.

So an example flow could look like this:

**1) create an employee with POST method:**

URL: `/api/v1/create`

req body:

```
{
    "name": "DorisWan",
    "salary": "50000",
    "age": "25"
}
```

res body:

```
{   
    "status":"success",
    "data":{
       "name":"DorisWan",
       "salary":"50000",
       "age":"25",
       "id":47
    }
}
```

**2) update the employee with PUT method:**

URL: `/api/v1/update/47` See how I took the `id` from the previous response body and put it into the URL.

req body:

```
{
    "name": "Doris",
    "salary": "60000",
    "age": "26"
}
```

res body:

```
{   
    "status":"success",
    "data":{
       "employee_name":"Doris",
       "employee_salary":"60000",
       "employee_age":"26",
       "id":47
    }
}
```